# ssh: id_rsa doesn't work, but if I rename it, it works

Tags: ssh, login, rsa

I have this id_rsa in my ~/.ssh folder. But it just doesn't authenticate. If I copy it and rename it to anything not id_rsa, it works.

```
[qfan@mycomputer .ssh]$ ls -al id_rsa id_rsa_good
-rw------- 1 qfan qfan 1766 Dec  3 18:35 id_rsa
-rw------- 1 qfan qfan 1766 Nov 20 19:43 id_rsa_good
[qfan@mycomputer .ssh]$ sha1sum id_rsa id_rsa_good
8cc7f68170038b184bba0541be7d105bb36f7d11  id_rsa
8cc7f68170038b184bba0541be7d105bb36f7d11  id_rsa_good
[qfan@mycomputer .ssh]$ ssh localhost -i id_rsa
qfan@localhost's password: 

[qfan@mycomputer .ssh]$ ssh localhost -i id_rsa_good
Enter passphrase for key 'id_rsa_good': 
Last login: Tue Dec  3 18:46:46 2013 from 127.0.0.1
[qfan@mycomputer ~]$ exit
logout
Connection to localhost closed.
```

Note that "ssh localhost -i id_rsa" fails and ssh starts to ask for regular password login.

I used -vvv and here's the diff of the logs:

```
[qfan@mycomputer .ssh]$ ssh localhost -i id_rsa_good -vvv 2> log1_good.txt
Enter passphrase for key 'id_rsa_good': 

[qfan@mycomputer .ssh]$ ssh localhost -i id_rsa -vvv 2> log2_bad.txt
qfan@localhost's password: 

[qfan@mycomputer .ssh]$ diff log1_good.txt log2_bad.txt 
7c7
< debug3: Not a RSA1 key file id_rsa_good.
---
> debug3: Not a RSA1 key file id_rsa.
41c41
< debug1: identity file id_rsa_good type -1
---
> debug1: identity file id_rsa type 1
81,82c81,82
< debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 126/256
< debug2: bits set: 533/1024
---
> debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 127/256
> debug2: bits set: 503/1024
90c90
< debug2: bits set: 506/1024
---
> debug2: bits set: 539/1024
103c103
< debug2: key: id_rsa_good ((nil))
---
> debug2: key: id_rsa (0x7f953ea96f90)
136,138c136,145
< debug1: Trying private key: id_rsa_good
< debug1: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
< debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
---
> debug1: Offering public key: id_rsa
> debug3: send_pubkey_test
> debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
> debug3: Wrote 368 bytes for a total of 1477
> debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
> debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
> debug3: authmethod_lookup password
> debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
> debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
> debug1: Next authentication method: password
[qfan@mycomputer .ssh]$
```

I also tried removing the passphrase from the key file, but it still doesn't work if named id_rsa.

So, what went wrong there?

-------EDIT-------

```
[qfan@mycomputer .ssh]$ file id_rsa
id_rsa: ASCII text
[qfan@mycomputer .ssh]$ cat id_rsa |head -n2
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
```

Comment: Are you sure the file contains an RSA key?  It kind of looks like when it is named id_rsa ssh assumes it is an rsa key (type 1), but when you name it id_rsa_good it isn't sure (type -1).

Comment: Can you run `file id_rsa` and let us see the output?  If it isn't something very much like `id_rsa: PEM RSA private key`, mfarver may well have a point!

Comment: It's text file:
[qfan@mycomputer .ssh]$ file id_rsa
id_rsa: ASCII text
[qfan@mycomputer .ssh]$ cat id_rsa |head -n2
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found the reason. My `id_rsa.pub` file in the same `.ssh` folder is a public key that belongs to a different identity file. When `id_rsa.pub` doesn't match `id_rsa,` it fails automatically. Removing or moving the `id_rsa.pub` file makes `id_rsa` work.

Comment: I would love to understand why this is so...

Comment: @DavidResnick I gave the answer to that question in https://serverfault.com/a/587560/214507